# Moving from Gnome to XFCE

Tags: linux, gnome, xfce

I'm using Gnome now and want to install XFCE. Nothing complicated but just curious - do all applications, installed previously on Gnome will be also removed or they would work on XFCE properly after installing XFCE and removing Gnome ?

OS: Linux Mint 7

Comment: This question doesn't really belong here. But you should be fine on XFCE, I've had no problems at all.

Comment: There's http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *might* lose functionality in any desktop widgets that were using Gnome, but in general, all of your application using GTK should not in any way be affected by what desktop environment you are using.

At least under Ubuntu, I am fairly sure that uninstalling Gnome should only affect the desktop environment, it should not remove any applications that are not explicitly tied to the Gnome desktop.

Comment: Well, most of the widget managers can be used under XFCE as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't uninstall Gnome, just select XFCE in the graphical login screen

Answer (score 2):

Installing XFCE is easy : as root, run:

```
yum groupinstall XFCE
```

In my experience, all gnome applications will work with XFCE. However, you should make sure that XFCE launches the appropriate services for these at startup. Navigate to Menu –> Settings –> Sessions & Startup. On the “Advanced” tab, select the appropriate checkbox.

There is no need to uninstall GNOME. The login screen will allow you to select one or the other.